# Disable redirect after product add to basket

Tags: cart, redirect, home

When I add something from the **`category`** to the **`basket/cart`** it redirects me to the `basket/cart`.

After searching I found that I could turn this functionality of in the admin system via

`Configuration > Sales | Checkout > After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart`

It now redirects to the Home page. I don't know if this a bug in the redirect?

Comment: No, thats not the case with default Magento Setup. It works completely fine when added from detail page or listing page. Have you done any modification in code or from which page are you trying to do so?

Comment: can you check log files.system.log or exception.log file

Comment: I am using a 3rd party theme. I have done some modification in the frontend/default/{theme_name}/template/product/list.phtml. The page loads okay when I click on it from the menu.

Comment: i have configured this setting so after add to cart click it's redirect me to same page..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look into the cart controller `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php` your will find the function `_goBack`. This is where the return url is decided by Magento.

```
protected function _goBack()
{
    $returnUrl = $this->getRequest()->getParam('return_url');
    if ($returnUrl) {

        if (!$this->_isUrlInternal($returnUrl)) {
            throw new Mage_Exception('External urls redirect to "' . $returnUrl . '" denied!');
        }

        $this->_getSession()->getMessages(true);
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($returnUrl);
    } elseif (!Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/cart/redirect_to_cart')
        && !$this->getRequest()->getParam('in_cart')
        && $backUrl = $this->_getRefererUrl()
    ) {
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($backUrl);
    } else {
        if (($this->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'add') && !$this->getRequest()->getParam('in_cart')) {
            $this->_getSession()->setContinueShoppingUrl($this->_getRefererUrl());
        }
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
    }
    return $this;
}
```

The section your are looking for is the call to `_getRefererUrl` this happens when you are not setting the return url as a parameter and not using the default redirect to cart option.

Inside the function `_getRefererUrl` the referrer url is checked to see if it is an internal url, when it is not internal than the base url is used.

I would suggest that either your referrer url is external or there is something wrong with the check.

Have a look at `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_isUrlInternal` to debug if the url is internal or not.

**Problem was that _isUrlInternal was failing because of having the port in the base url**

Comment: I am very new to Magento and never debugged anything before in Magengto. What is the process involved so I can debug this URL

Comment: @user9252 there are may ways you could go about doing this, what I would suggest could be the easiest would be simply to add a few var_dumps of variables in the function to see what is going on.

Comment: I put a debug call after $returnUrl = $this->getRequest()->getParam('return_url'); and it was blank, any suggestions.

Comment: do the same but for $backUrl

Comment: it returned http://192.168.1.20:80/magento/

Comment: step into the function `_isUrlInternal` and see what is not matching there

Comment: The url passed into the function is http://192.168.1.20/magento/test-product-category.html

Comment: looks like you have a difference between your base url settings in the admin, do they have the port set in them?

Comment: I am using Bitnami, and using the default settings. The default setting is http://192.168.1.20:80/magento/. Do I remove the port?

Comment: I have removed the port number :80 from the base url. Flush the cache. It now redirects back to the category list page as planned.

Comment: @user9252 great, I have updated my answer to include this note

Answer (score 4):

In addition to david-manners answer, you as well may have issues with your `web/unsecure/base_url` & `web/secure/base_url` being set correctly without ports - but your actual app vhost (apache/nginx) listening on some port other than 80/443, e.g. when running behind varnish.

This will result in `\Mage_Core_Helper_Url::getCurrentUrl`, used e.g. for adding the *base64 encoded* query params - decoded and used by `_getRefererUrl` having the 'non-default' port as part of the url. (e.g. http://www.domain.com:81/your-url.html)

As a result `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_isUrlInternal` returns false...

> For further reference, see
>   http://erikeng.se/post/magento-behind-varnish.html
>
> **A clean and good solution is described in**
>   https://serverfault.com/questions/318151/how-to-set-php-server-port-var-to-80-behind-varnish

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your `web/unsecure/base_url` & `web/secure/base_url` with `127.0.0.1` in place of `localhost`. For me it worked.